# Problem with pytorch dataset.imageFolder with custom dataset in Google Colab

Tags: python-imaging-library, classification, google-colaboratory, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to load a dataset for a classification task using pytorch, this is the code i use:

```
data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomRotation(2.8),
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5), (0.5))
    ]),
    'valid': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5), (0.5))
    ])
}
print(os.listdir())
# TODO: Load the datasets with ImageFolder
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join("/content/drive/MyDrive/DatasetPersonale", x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'valid']}
# TODO: Using the image datasets and the trainforms, define the dataloaders
batch_size = 32
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=batch_size,
                                             shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
              for x in ['train', 'valid']}
class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes
print(class_names)
dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'valid']}
```

the code worked fine but as my dataset was in grayscale, I needed to convert it to RGB so I used this code:

```
rootdir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/DatasetPersonale/trainRGB'
print("Train")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
   for file in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        name = os.path.basename(filePath)
        img=Image.open(filePath, mode="r")
        print(img.mode)
        if img.mode != "RGB":
            RGBimg=img.convert("RGB")
            RGBimg.save(filePath,format=jpeg)
```

now my images are still jpeg, but now they are RGB and not L. the problem is that if I go to rerun the code to load the dataset I get this error

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-3dace4b0f21b> in <module>()
     19 image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join("/content/drive/MyDrive/DatasetPersonale", x),
     20                                           data_transforms[x])
---> 21                   for x in ['trainRGB', 'validRGB']}
     22 
     23 # TODO: Using the image datasets and the trainforms, define the dataloaders

4 frames
<ipython-input-15-3dace4b0f21b> in <dictcomp>(.0)
     19 image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join("/content/drive/MyDrive/DatasetPersonale", x),
     20                                           data_transforms[x])
---> 21                   for x in ['trainRGB', 'validRGB']}
     22 
     23 # TODO: Using the image datasets and the trainforms, define the dataloaders

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py in __init__(self, root, transform, target_transform, loader, is_valid_file)
    311                                           transform=transform,
    312                                           target_transform=target_transform,
--> 313                                           is_valid_file=is_valid_file)
    314         self.imgs = self.samples

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py in __init__(self, root, loader, extensions, transform, target_transform, is_valid_file)
    144                                             target_transform=target_transform)
    145         classes, class_to_idx = self.find_classes(self.root)
--> 146         samples = self.make_dataset(self.root, class_to_idx, extensions, is_valid_file)
    147 
    148         self.loader = loader

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py in make_dataset(directory, class_to_idx, extensions, is_valid_file)
    190                 "The class_to_idx parameter cannot be None."
    191             )
--> 192         return make_dataset(directory, class_to_idx, extensions=extensions, is_valid_file=is_valid_file)
    193 
    194     def find_classes(self, directory: str) -> Tuple[List[str], Dict[str, int]]:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py in make_dataset(directory, class_to_idx, extensions, is_valid_file)
    100         if extensions is not None:
    101             msg += f"Supported extensions are: {', '.join(extensions)}"
--> 102         raise FileNotFoundError(msg)
    103 
    104     return instances

FileNotFoundError: Found no valid file for the classes .ipynb_checkpoints. Supported extensions are: .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .ppm, .bmp, .pgm, .tif, .tiff, .webp
```

Does someone know why this error appears? I checked the extension of all the files and they are jpeg.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you copy all your grayscale images to `/content/drive/MyDrive/DatasetPersonale/trainRGB` beforehand? Otherwise, `for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):` for `rootdir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/DatasetPersonale/trainRGB'` won't do anything, since there are no files!? Or: Are there proper files in `/content/drive/MyDrive/DatasetPersonale/trainRGB`?

Comment: yes i copied every grayscale image in trainRGB, the files in the folder are okay and they are all RGB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**: This is because of `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder inside the folder `/content/drive/MyDrive/DatasetPersonale/trainRGB` which contains files (invalid images) cannot be read as images that have valid extensions (.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .ppm, .bmp, .pgm, .tif, .tiff, .webp).

**Solution**: You can save all your images in a subfolder namely 'images' and then change your root folder to `/content/drive/MyDrive/DatasetPersonale/trainRGB/images` to avoid reading the `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder with your images.